# Signals send over a channel

Tags: statistics

Signals are being send over a channel. A signal is either a 0 or a 1.

An error can occur during transmission, and a 1 could be received while a 0 was sent, and a 0 could be received while a 1 was sent. The chance of an error occurring is $\frac{1}{10}$.

This chance is too high they find, and they opt to send the same signal *three* times, while still having a chance of error of $\frac{1}{10}$.

After receiving the three signals it is assumed that the signal with the highest frequency was the original signal.

How big is the chance that after this adjustment a wrong conclusion is made about the original signal?

---

The first thing I did was find out how many possibilities there are for sending a signal three times and receiving any combination of outputs. There are $2^3 = 8$ possibilities. E.g., sending a 0 three times could end up being received as

000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.

In four of these cases, it goes awriiight: 000, 001, 010, 100. In the other four cases it won't go right; if an assumption would be made, then the assumption would be that a 1 was sent and not a 0.

In my simplistic thinking, I would say that there's a 50% chance of making the wrong assumption, but I can't believe the answer to be this simple. Therefore, I would like some pointers to how I can try to solve this question.

Since this is part of my statistics course, my mind is racing all over the place. Is it suggested that I state a null hypothesis? Or is it something far simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the three received bits, an incorrect conclusion will be reached if *at least* $2$ of the bits are wrong.

The probability that $2$ bits are wrong is ${3 \choose 2}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)$, while the probability that all $3$ bits will be wrong is ${3 \choose 3}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^3$.

The total probability that an incorrect conclusion will be reached is the sum of the two probabilities, and so will be ${3 \choose 2}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\frac{9}{10}+{3 \choose 3}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^3$ which equals $\frac{7}{250}$.

Comment: "If at least 2" was the jump I had to make. I don't know why I fail to see these things. Anyways, thank you for your insight!

Comment: Though I wonder, isn't p reserved for success? It seems you took $\frac{1}{10}$ as a success while this is the chance an error occurs.

Comment: The error probability of $\frac{1}{10}$ is correctly taken into account. When  you have exactly $2$ bits in error, there is only $1$ bit successfully received - the probability of this is $\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{9}{10}$. There are $3$ ways of obtaining this, hence the ${3 \choose 2}$ factor. When all $3$ bits are in error, the probability is $\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{1}{10}\times\frac{1}{10}$, and there is only $1$ way of obtaining this.